# Avoiding/reducing multiple installations for Travis-CI builds

Tags: linux, matrix, travis-ci, coverity, jailhouse

For our Travis-CI builds of the [Jailhouse hypervisor](https://github.com/siemens/jailhouse), we have a rather costly environment setup which consists of a partial distribution update to pull in a recent make version (>=3.82, the default one is still only 3.81 - Ubuntu...), a cross toolchain for ARM and a 100 MB package of prebuilt Linux kernel sources that we need to compile an out-of-tree module.

To reduce the build time and the number of kernel downloads, we currently build all configuration variants sequentially in a single run (make; make clean; make...). That was fine for checking for build breakages, but with the addition of a Coverity scan, which depends on the build outputs, it no longer works. Switching to a build matrix seems the obvious solution, at the price of multiple installations because Travis-CI seems to be unable to reuse them during such builds. While we currently only have 3 configuration variants, this will increase in the future (e.g. every ARM board added will increase it by one), thus the approach does not really scale.

Do we have any alternatives? I already looked at caching, available via the docker-based build, but lacking sudo support there prevents this approach. Other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your build to do this

```
cov-build --idir <target1> make; make clean
...
```

Use different intermediate directories for each build.  Then go back later and run

```
cov-analyze --idir <target1>
cov-commit-defects --idir <target1> --stream <target1>
```

Comment: Hmm, this is different from what the standard travisci_build_coverity_scan.sh does right now. What do those commands replace in that script, the single cov-build step?
Where are those interfaces documented? How stable are they? I'm concerned this could break quickly when Coverity changes their procedure, at least for Travis-CI.
Nevertheless, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: True, but you're doing something very different.  Your build is building and cleaning multiple times, so you want to capture each build. 

Cov-build is what captures the build, cov-analyze runs the analysis, cov-commit-defects puts the defects in CIM.

Comment: Getting closer: We want streams in order to manage configuration variants (like different target architectures or boards) - but we will probably not get them as [OSS project](https://communities.coverity.com/message/6109). Checking with Coverity...
PS: When using the free cloud-based scan, you don't have local analysis (cov-analyze, cov-commit-defects).

Comment: Ah yes, Professional Services are probably the best people to talk about your needs.  You might also want to check out CodeSpotter.